# "A robo directive was not used in the crawl." and test is not running. Why?

Tags: android, firebase-test-lab

Recently I facing issue in Firebase test lab report says "A robo directive was not used in the crawl." what is this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If a dev provides custom login credentials (e.g., username and password) for the crawler to use during crawl, but the crawler fails to make use of those, then this warning is shown.